# How do I get random numbers rather than random numbers and letters?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to make random three digit number but when I run it, it generates alphanumeric characters.  I want to just get a random three digit number.

generate:

```
function () {
    this.newItem.st = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 3).toUpperCase() +
                      Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 4).toUpperCase()
}
```

[image: Scren shot]

When I click generate I want to get random values of just 0-9 not A-Z.

Comment: please add some examples of the wanted values.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range - Set the range from 100-999. In PHP (as you've tagged it), `random_int(100, 999)` (PHP 7+).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Comment: What does this have to do with `java` and `php`?

Comment: take 3 dijit number similar 234  923 012 038 482 ....

Comment: `this.newItem.st = ((Math.floor(Math.random()*1000+5)*10+.5)/10000).toString().split(".")[1].replace(/05$/,"");`

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your random number by 10 to get into the one's place, use Math.floor to get an integer, and then convert to string to get a string of numbers:

```
const el = document.getElementById("output");
el.innerHTML = getNumber();
function getNumber() {
    let myNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
    return  myNum;
}
```